# LeafletJs: how to tell if a cluster group's tooltip is open?

Tags: leaflet, tooltip, leaflet.markercluster

```
        $scope.companyMarkersClusterGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
            if (layer.isPopupOpen()){
               console.log('tooltip is open');
```

reports that that tooltip is open for the tooltip of a single marker, but not for the tooltip of a cluster group marker. The tooltip ***is*** open, just not reported as such. How can I detect that it is open?

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#getting-the-visible-parent-of-a-marker

Comment: Looks helpful. Thanks. Want to work it up into an answer? Btw, your profile says that you work at Nordic. Can you answer [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/ble-5-1-wearable-dev-board)?  I am looking for a dev board with AoA / AoD for precise positioning. Something battery powered, with a reasonable life, wearable for tracking people would be a bonus, but also tracing assets is fine. Sorry to be cheeky, but I would be ***very*** grateful if you could ask around the office & post an answer there. Thanks, and stay healthy